# How can I get all resources that of a particular resource type using cluster.exe?

Tags: windows, cluster, failovercluster

On a Windows failover cluster environment, we can use the command `cluster resourcetype` to get all available resource types. My question is, how can I get all the resources that is belong to this resource type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

List all cluster resources:

```
cluster.exe res
```

List all resources of specific type:

```
cluster.exe res | find "[resource type]"
```